# How to count unique value depending on the next cell using excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have 2 column, A and B:

```
2020/07/06  21:31:41
2020/07/06  21:31:51
2020/07/06  21:35:42
2020/07/06  21:36:15
2020/07/07  21:33:14
2020/07/07  21:36:24
2020/07/07  21:36:24
2020/07/07  21:39:52
2020/07/07  21:39:52
2020/07/07  21:40:19
2020/07/07  21:40:19
2020/07/07  21:49:19
```

I want to automatically generate the count of **unique value** on column B depending on my input.

For example, if my input is `2020/07/07`, in this case the output should be `5`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below formula where `C1` holds the criterion date:

`=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A12=C1,B1:B12),IF(A1:A12=C1,B1:B12))>0))`

Note: Depending on your Excel version, you may or may not have to array enter this formula i.e. make use of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> which will show wrapping braces when correctly done.

If you have O365 and access to UNIQUE formula then you can use:

`=COUNT(UNIQUE(IF(A1:A12=C1,B1:B12),FALSE,FALSE))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`/`COUNTIF` functions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E1=A1:A12)*(1/COUNTIF(B1:B12,B1:B12)))
```

[image]